# Apache Tomcat Auto Start on reboot

Tags: macos, apache

I followed these instructions to install Tomcat 8 on OS X El Capitan

https://wolfpaulus.com/journal/mac/tomcat8/

### These instructions had section on start/stop using script

- /Library/Tomcat/bin/startup.sh
- /Library/Tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

### Questions

How can i make these script start and stop tomcat on OS Startup and Shutdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using login/logoff hooks.

https://support.apple.com/de-at/HT2420

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CustomLogin.html

https://wiki.afp548.com/index.php/Login/Logout_Hooks_in_OS_X

Note. I should have posted this as a comment, but I do not have the rep.